# Problems with reusing the code in php

Tags: php, html

Hi there i have two download functionalities...

At one instance i am using dropdown box to download the file which posts the chosen value to php logic....

```
 $file = $_POST['file'];
```

In second instance i am using a link to download the file..

```
 $file = $_GET["file"];
```

I want to implement DRY principle, so can i do something like  `$file1 = $_POST['file'] or $_GET["file"];` which works in both instances... rather than recreating the file....

Comment: What are you talking about? Note, if this is about the benefits and pitfalls of using GET and POST, keep in mind they are not really supposed to be interchangeable.

Comment: `$file = $_REQUEST['file']`? It's really not clear what you're having trouble with.

Comment: The above code worked fine thank you.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$_REQUEST` to access variables from both GET and POST. However, in this case make sure to check the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to prevent the code that should run in case of POST to work with GET.

Comment: Wasn't `$_REQUEST` to be deprecated some time ago?

Comment: @JaredFarrish wasn't PHP deprecated some time ago? :P

Comment: Man, I sure remember there being some kind of controversy with using this superglobal (and still think it's probably usually a bad idea). @dbf - Only for Perl 6. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine if the value was POSTed or GETed (GOT?), you can use [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```
if(isset($_POST["file"])){
    //POST stuff
}elseif(isset($_GET["file"])){
    //GET stuff
}else{
    //error
}
```